# Can I request for a change of a musical piece assigned to me due to physical discomfort?

Tags: coursework, health, homework

I wonder if this is going to sound silly, I'd rather vent this anonymously online first before taking any action in the real world... I'm doing a Bachelor's Degree in Creative Writing and part of our next assignment is on Mozart. The music they've selected us to analyze is his Horn Concerto No. 2. Due to my autistic spectrum disorder, I find certain frequencies/noises to be irritating to listen to, it's this sort of throbbing in my inner ear like when you listen to something that is too loud or at the wrong frequency. I think it's related to my sensory processing disorder in some way, I have similar issues with tactile sensations. The Horn Concerto causes this throbbing/vibration and trying to analyze it is uncomfortable/painful.

This sounds ridiculous but would it be wrong of me to ask my tutor if I could do another piece of his music like Lacrimosa/Requiem or the 9th Symphony for one half of my assignment? I enjoy both those pieces, Mozart has such a wide variety of music to choose from and I'd hate to have to choose something else just because of my condition. Feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question per se, but it’s quite easy using common music apps to take an audio file and shift all the frequencies up or down by some desired amount without changing the tempo. The sound quality degrades a bit but not by much. If your discomfort is really associated only with specific frequencies, consider the possibility that that will solve the issue and allow you to complete the assignment without making any requests.

Comment: There is even easier path to try. Try listening to the same piece performed by different people, or even on a different instrument. Almost anything more or less well known can be found played on piano.

Comment: I did this once, of course its ok.

Comment: Personally, if I set an assessment task that caused physical discomfort for one of my students then I would *want* them to tell me so that I could change it.

Comment: Any request has more weight if you have a (medical) doctor in your side, if you are met with refusal, offer to come back with a letter from your doctor.  I would expect that the university rules require him to accomodate your needs.

Comment: I think you have a disabled access requirement to study a different piece of music. I'm disabled; my experience is that when I say 'I have disabled access requirement X', this language helps. Your additional needs sound very reasonable to me; certainly not ridiculous. In general I think people are required to make reasonable adjustments for such things

Answer (score 61):

> would it be wrong of me to ask my tutor if I could do another piece of his music like Lacrimosa/Requiem or the 9th Symphony for one half of my assignment?

No, it wouldn't be unreasonable to ask and in many places accommodation would be required by law. But in some other places what they *should* do and what they *will* do might be quite different. I would hope that the UK requires appropriate accommodation.

But you should ask and explain your reasoning. In fact, since the program isn't one in music at all, it might be necessary for someone like me (almost completely deaf and totally deaf in certain frequencies) to use a completely different assignment that doesn't depend on normal hearing.

I've had to give up music - even Bob Dylan - sad.

Comment: Have you had a look at [bone conduction headphones](https://www.soundguys.com/bone-conduction-headphones-20580/)?

Answer (score 16):

You're majoring in Writing. Write about how irritated you get with those notes and yes, emphasize your spectrum disorder. That should give your prof a fresh perspective about how "other" people view Mozart. You could do a whole book about this even to a point comparing autistic and neurotypicals who also hate listening to that type of music.

Comment: The OP describes it as "uncomfortable/painful". I don't think they should have to suffer through discomfort and pain to get their point across to the professor. If I was the professor and I read an assignment written like this, I would ask the student: why didn't you just tell me so I could give you a different piece to write about?

Comment: On the other hand, if this is something that OP *wants* to do, there's nothing stopping them from clearing this with their Professor first. They can both make sure this can be done in a way that still accomplishes the goals of the assignment, and this avoids getting into a situation like the one @kaya3 describes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with hating Mozart.

Answer (score 8):

> This sounds ridiculous

It's not ridiculous, you're feeling physical discomfort. Plus, how can you be inspired to write creatively by something that's mostly grating for you to even listen to?

> but would it be wrong of me to ask my tutor etc.

It's perfectly fine, but:

- Your tutor might give you some sort of excuse, like "I have to give everyone the same piece" or "I can't make this decision myself" or whatever. I don't think that's a valid excuse, but it might happen.
- Make an effort your request to sound respectful and non-aggressive, and not like a demand. You've explained it pretty well here, i.e. focusing on how it affects you; just make sure to use an appropriate tone of voice. Also, don't make a concrete suggestion for an alternative piece; rather, first wait for your tutor to acknowledge the problem, and either ask you for a suggestion or start wondering out loud what to do.
- Your tutor might have another alternative, e.g. using a painting instead of a musical piece; or even letting the other assignments have more weight in the final grade and letting you skip this one.

Comment: I agree, especially with the point of not suggesting specific pieces. This might give rise to the thought that you want it, because you know it well already. Instead explain what exactly is the problem and with which kind of music you are fine and giving some pieces as examples for which is ok. And speaking from experience, most professors are quite understanding in such regards (speaking from the point of view as a graduate student and tutor).

Answer (score 7):

Asking for accommodation is fine -- remembering that there are laws that dictate whether such a request must be honored, and that many profs will respond to polite and timely requests, whether they are required to or not.

I don't think you should recommend a piece for replacement though.  That might offer you an advantage over other students.  My preference would be to do your best to communicate what disturbs you in the original piece (perhaps indicating times of such passages in a recording), examples of works that don't disturb you, and ask the prof to do their best to offer you an option that you wouldn't find disturbing.

Comment: If I were the professor, I would welcome the suggestion of an alternative.  Otherwise, I'd have to spend a lot of time listening to different pieces of music, trying to guess what would or wouldn't cause OP's discomfort.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  -- the point is that a pre-familiarity with a piece may prove an unfair advantage.  Perhaps an alternate assignment assessing the same metrics is the best option.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly ask but there are several potential issues with your request.  I'm always reluctant to modify an assignment for a student because, if I do it for one student, then I have to be willing to do it for everyone.  I understand that you have a situation that makes the assignment problematic but I have no way of confirming that and I definitely don't want to put myself in the position of trying to decide what constitutes a good reason and what doesn't.

It's true that faculty are legally required to provide accommodations for students with disabilities but this is only the case for disabilities that have been confirmed by the university.  We can't make this decision unilaterally and, for better or worse, this is a situation that the federal government takes very seriously.  That means that there are lawyers involved and, whenever lawyers get involved, things get very rigid.  I'm required to give students the accommodations the disability office has decide they get and I'm specifically required not to do anything else.  If I do, we're back to having potential fairness issues with the other students in the class.

The path forward for you should be to go to the disability services office at your school, provide them documentation of your condition (or find out what documentation they want to see) and have them provide an official accommodation notice that you give to your professors.  Unfortunately, that's a process that probably won't be done in time for this assignment.

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with this, but I would point out that it seems to me that you are answering based on an unconfirmed assumption that the OP has not reported his condition/disability to their University.

Comment: In the UK (mentioned in the OP's profile) a disability does not have to be "confirmed", and ASD disorders are really hard to get diagnosed, even in childhood. Obviously a diagnosis helps, and it's good practice not to spring something unexpected on the organisation, but having been notified of a disability qualifying under the Disability Discrimination Act, the duty to accommodate applies. Disputes need to be dealt with by the courts, but "You don't have a disability" is quite uncommon. [A reasonable adjustment may be to suggest a different work of Mozart's, or a different arrangement of it.]

Comment: This may just be my opinion but, you *should* be willing to modify the assignment for every student.  If there is an innate problem with the assignment, such that *every* student is asking you to change it, it would be extremely stubborn of you not to change it.

Comment: I really don't see how there would be any fairness issue raised by the professor simply assigning a different piece of music from the list of pieces of music they must already have drawn up for the task. If the pieces aren't all of equal difficulty to write about then the assessment was already unfair, otherwise if they are of equal difficulty to write about then assigning a different one is still fair. I also agree with Zibbobz; "if I do the right thing once then I will have to do the right thing more times" is not a good argument against doing the right thing.

Comment: For *some kinds* of accommodation request, I would agree with this answer’s stance — when they compromise the fairness/appropriateness of the assignment, or put a large extra burden on the instructors.  But for requests like this, which seem easy to grant, I don’t see any reason to be unwilling.

Comment: @kaya3   You made some huge assumptions.  Why "must they already have [other pieces] drawn up for the task"?  When I create an assignment, I don't create five equivalent versions so that I have backups in case someone has an issue with the first one.  Also, the OP mentioned already being familiar with the other pieces he suggested which would give him an advantage over other students who were likely hearing the other piece for the first time.

Comment: -1. OP has a disabled access requirement to study a different piece of music. Your approach is essentially, 'I don't want to take responsibility for helping you, come back when the system has certified your situation so I don't have to think about it'. I'm disabled and the system discriminates against me in many different ways. Getting certified can take a very long time and cause all sorts of difficulties; your approach added on to that process can cause a lot of additional suffering in my experience

Comment: @Joe My approach is, "There's a process in place for handling your situation.  You should go and use it."  And you're right - I'm not taking responsibility for evaluating your condition, getting the documentation to confirm that it is what you say it is then determining what accommodations are appropriate.  Again, that's why we have a process and it's been my experience as an instructor that US school's often go overboard in the accommodations they require.

Comment: @G. Allen, I think you're lacking the experience of starting that kind of process, and finding that it's still going after a number of months without any useful response. I'm not saying you need to take responsibility for evaluating people's condition etc., I'm saying that if people come to you with disabled access requirements, you can take responsibility for helping them by making reasonable adjustments regardless of whether they have documentation or not. It took me two years of being too ashamed of my disability to get any kind of documentation.

Comment: +1 @G.Allen, without any kind of formal confirmation of the issue it is a minefield, better to let those entrusted with the process deal with this.